# Python compare >, <

Tags: python, comparison-operators

Can some one explain the following

```
print("5<7<3 ",5<7<3) 
print("(5<7)<3 ",(5<7)<3) 
print("5<(7<3) ",5<(7<3)) 
print("5>(7<3) ", 5>(7<3))
print("(5<7)>3 ",(5<7)>3)
print("(5<7)<1 ",(5<7)<1)
```

Output is:

```
Line 1 - 5<7<3  False 
Line 2 - (5<7)<3  True
Line 3 - 5<(7<3)  False
Line 4 - 5>(7<3)  True
Line 5 - (5<7)>3  False
Line 6 - (5<7)<1  False
```

I am confused how come output in line 3, and 4 are giving True and False.
As I understand x

Comment: (5<7) is True. True < 3 is True, because True == 1.

Comment: Do you understand the _other_ lines with `(...)`? If so, how do you interpret those lines.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Associativity of comparison operators in Python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32536217/associativity-of-comparison-operators-in-python)

Comment: @Georgy I don't think that really answers the question. Knowing how operator chaining works is one thing, but you *also* have to know that booleans are integers.

Comment: @Aran-Fey It's all there https://stackoverflow.com/a/32536368/7851470

Answer (score 2):

Line 3 - `5<(7<3)  False`

`(7<3)` is `False` which is `0` in context of Python, now `5<0` is `False`.

Line 4 - `5>(7<3)  True`

Similarly, `7<3` is `False` which is also `0`, so `5>0` is `True`.

For other lines, if a condition leads to `True`, it would be rendered as `1` by Python for subsequent condition checks.

Answer (score 0):

Line 3 - (7 < 3)  resolves to 0 which is not more than 5 => False.
Line 4 - (7 < 3)  resolves to 0 which is less than 5 => True.

Answer (score 0):

Simply evaluate the answer of the parenthesis:

And remember False = 0 and True = 1

So, line 3 and 4:

```
print("5<(7<3) ",5<(7<3)) 
print("5>(7<3) ", 5>(7<3))
```

would be

1) 5<(False) i,e  5 < 0 which is False.

2) 5 > False i,e 5 > 0 which is True